# UrlEncodedFormEntity does not insert params into entity

Tags: post

I am trying to insert parameters into http post with UrlEncodedFormEntity but failing.

```
 UrlEncodedFormEntity temp2 = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formParams);
```

formParams is an Array list which contains 1 BasicNameValuePair element: ship_it=true

when the temp2 variable returns it returns with out the parameters and then when I do:

```
((HttpPost) request).setEntity(temp2);
```

the request does not contain the parameters.

any tip to why this is not working?

Comment: I have tried adding parameters to the http request in this format: basicParams.setBooleanParameter("ship_it" , true);
((HttpPost) request).setParams(basicParams);
request.setHeader("ship_it" , "true");  still no go

Comment: hi , any help would be appriciated